# Which site is more reasonable for questions about R, SO or stats.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, cross-posting, site-recommendation

I've been using SO for a little over a year now, and recently I've noticed a shift of users between SO and stats.stackexchange.com.

I'm wondering if there has been any discussion on where questions about R, a statistical environment, best fits. Would you say it's better to ask R questions on SO or would it be better to ask over at stats.stackexchange.com? What, if any, determinants would you use to decide to post between the two? What about cross posting?

Comment: Because your bio SO says "I like turtles" I have to ask are you in anyway related to this kid: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMNry4PE93Y

Answer (score 11):

You could probably do either one. It seems like an overlap. But, I would say, if it has more to do with language itself instead of the stats put on stackoverflow otherwise put it on stats.exchange.com if the problem has more to do with the stats.

Comment: perfectly stated.. same sort of advice I give about URL rewriting questions. "if you consider yourself a system administrator, ask on Server Fault.. if you consider yourself a programmer, ask on Stack Overflow."

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @neilfws, the only thing I would suggest would be not to start juggling questions from one site to the other because "it's more programming" or "it's more stats"... because THAT would be annoying.

I personally have `r` as a favourite tag in the two sites and watch them both, I don't have too many problems with that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add that cross-posting should definitely lead to a closure on one of both sites. Right now, I answered a question only to find out it had a valid answer on the other site later on. Bloody annoying that is.  Thing is, when a question really grabs me I like to spend some time figuring out how it's solved best. Especially when there's some statistics involved, answering it takes a good deal of thinking.

For the rest, I agree with the "programming on SO, statistics on stats.stackexchange" policy.

Comment: If only there was a way to enforce this.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that it depends on whether the question is focused more on understanding the statistical method or how to implement the method using R code.  The former would go to stats.exchange.com, the latter to SO with the 'r' tag.

However, there is bound to be a grey area with some overlap, so I hope people focus more on providing high-quality answers than on debating where a specific question should be posted.

Comment: What do you mean with `stats.exchange.com`? This doesn't exists.